# Getting "NotesException: Not implemented" exception while invoking session.getCalendar(string,string)

Tags: lotus-domino

I am using Lotus Domino 9.0.1.Was using Notes API for Java(Remotely) to get the calendar items.Copied NCSO.jar from server(domino\data\domino\java\NCSO.jar) and given the same as a classpath in my eclipse.But when i try to invoke session.getCalendar(string,string) method it is giving "NotesException: Not implemented" error.

Comment: The title of this question is misleading.  It refers to Session.getDatabase(), but the description says the exception is thrown from Session.getCalendar().  @Anil, please consider editing the title.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different answer than Richard's.  Since Notes & Domino 9.0, the Java Session interface does include a getCalendar method [documented here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETCALENDAR_METHOD_SESSION_JAVA.html).  It's the way you get an instance of NotesCalendar.

However, there are two implementations of Session: 1) The "local" implementation exported by Notes.jar, and 2) the "remote" implementation exported by NCSO.jar.  The getCalendar method is only implemented in Notes.jar.

Of course, if you really need to use NCSO.jar, this amounts to the same answer.  The "remote" version of Session.getCalendar() is not implemented.

Comment: Interesting that we pointed to the exact same doc page.It's not there in the actual list of methods on the page so I didn't think it existed, but in the example section of the page it does include getCalendar.

Comment: I am trying to access the Domino API's remotely.Is there anyway i can do all my CRUD operations for meeting  using API's.

Answer (score 0):

The getCalendar method is not available in the Session class of Notes API for Java.  See the [API documentation here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS_JAVA.html).

That method is only exposed in the [classes for SSJS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_domino_Session.html).

Comment: Thanks Richard.Is there any way i can create calendar item with using REST apis.

Comment: Yes, the Domino Access Services REST API exposes a Calendar Service.  See here for the POST request for calendar events. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Calendar_events_POST&content=apicontent

Comment: getCalendar method is there in the link(http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETCALENDAR_METHOD_SESSION_JAVA.html) what you provided for 9.0.1.